# How can i restore the tablestructure and recover data when i drop table column

Tags: oracle, recovery

i have some test table

```
create table test123(ids number,emp_name varchar(100));
```

next i insert 1 record into the table and commit the changes

```
insert into test123 values(1,'asdzxc')
```

after that i issue

```
alter table test123
drop column emp_name;
```

can i restore the table structure to before i drop the column and recover the data 'asdzxc' which is stored in the dropped column

Comment: You would do a point in time recovery using your normal backups. Flashback won’t work applying undo when there has been DDL.

Comment: so i have to restore the datafile from the backup and issue a incomplete recovery to the time before i dropped the column correct?

Comment: Yes, if you only want to do a single table, you would restore to a temporary staging database and export/import the table, If you’re on a sufficiently recent Oracle version you can do this in one line in RMAN https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/rman-table-point-in-time-recovery-12cr1